# Post form when textarea change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I want to post a form when the form's children onchange() with jQuery.

This is my HTML Example:

```
<form class="tips">
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

And here is my jQuery code.

```
$('.tips textarea').onchange( function() {
// how to select the form is better ?
})
```

Edit:

If I have many form like this in the same page, how to submit the form when it's textarea  change?

Answer (score 1):

The change event will not work for a `textarea` (also jQuery does not have an `onchange` function) try using the blur event and checking if the value of the `textarea` is not empty.

```
$('.tips textarea').blur( function() {
    if($(this).val()){
        console.log($("form.tips"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, If I have many form like this in the same page, how can I submit when it's textarea change?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.tips textarea').onchange( function() {
     $('.tips').submit(function(e){
         //Do your stuff..
     });
})
```